# VBA Syntax error calling Shell object

Tags: vba, syntax-highlighting, syntax

In my VBA script, I have written code to create another .vbs script and write a line of code to that script.

Here is the code:

```
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\user\documents\invis.vbs", True)
    a.WriteLine ("CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False")
    a.Close
```

I believe the code is all correct and fully functional however, there is a syntax error that I cannot seem to fix. The error is in this line: `a.WriteLine ("CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False")` specifically in this part: `("Wscript.Shell")`. The syntax error is because of the quotes around the `Wscript.shell`.

I get a syntax error that says "use a list separator or )" with  `"Wscript.Shell"` highlighted.

If I remove the " ", the syntax error is gone, but I need the "" for the script to work.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You might not like this answer as it uses JScript and not VBS.  I used to have a tool to convert them back and forth but I have no idea where that thing lives now.

We hates VBS and both are run through the same WSH engine.  VBS is useful when you have to use things that deal with SAFEARRAY (which is a PITA from Js).  Some COM calls require SAFEARRAY and although you can do that from JS, the code gets huge and ugly where in VBS, it is all wrapped under the hood.  One example of this is some of the functions you might call for WMI need SAFEARRAY to populate the argument list.

I just wrote this and it workses just fine.

```js
var oFso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var oTextFile = oFso.CreateTextFile("C:\\Users\\user\\documents\\invis.js", true);
oTextFile.WriteLine("var oShell = new ActiveXObject(\"WScript.Shell\");");
oTextFile.WriteLine("oShell.Run( WScript.arguments(0), 0, false )" );
oTextFile.Close();
```

Again, apologies for JS but (IMHO) VBS is a ghastly language when there is a clean alternative that does the same thing.

One thing to observe is that there is no need for a "one liner" in your code.
It makes the code less readable and solves nothing.